# Update Combobox Value into Database

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, combobox

So, I might be going about this the wrong way, but I think it should work regardless.  I have a ListBox which loads its items from the database.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateListBox">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="cbNonFat" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="14,0,10,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsNonFat, Mode=TwoWay}">
            </CheckBox>

            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" Grid.Column="4" Name="cbbSeason"  Margin="0,0,10,0" Tag="{Binding Season, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="cbbSeason_Loaded" SelectionChanged="cbbSeason_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Year Round" Tag="0"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Spring/Summer" Tag="1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Fall/Winter" Tag="2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Featured" Tag="3"/>
            </ComboBox>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ListBox Name="lbFlavors" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateListBox}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the codebehind, I change Tag to the Selected Index:

```
    private void cbbSeason_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ComboBoxItem cbi in (sender as ComboBox).Items)
        {
            if (cbi.Content.ToString() == (sender as ComboBox).Tag.ToString())
            {
                (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(cbi.Tag);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, when the selection is changed, I update the Tag:

```
    private void cbbSeason_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ComboBox).Tag = (cbbSeason.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
    }
```

When I save the changes back to the database, the checkbox changes are successful, but not the combobox.  If I put a breakpoint on the cbbSeason_SelectionChanged event, the Tag isn't getting updated at all, so obviously that is the problem, but I don't know why it isn't getting updated.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I changed the bottom code to this to fix it:                                                            `private void cbbSeason_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ComboBoxItem cbi in (sender as ComboBox).Items)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(cbi.Tag) == (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex)
                {
                    (sender as ComboBox).Tag = cbi.Content;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: How do you save the changes to the database?